# Bad Gateway - NGINX Load Balancer Cloudflare

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, gateway, cloudflare

I have configured an NGINX 'load-balancer' to sit in front of my site. Right now my backend consists of only one server, but I plan to add more to actually utilize the 'load-balancing' of NGINX. If I access the load-balancer directly (i.e. with IP) I can access the site, and the proxy headers are being added correctly. However, if I point my DNS records at the balancer, I get a bad gateway error from Cloudflare. My understanding was that my A record for my site should now point at the load balancer sitting in front of my servers. Is that not correct? I'm having trouble understanding how I could access the site directly through the load balancer IP but when I change my A record it blows up. Any help helps. Cheers.

Comment: Does your site respond properly when you add to your hosts file something like:
`1.2.3.4 mysite.com` 
Yes, your A record should point to the IP that the frontend is bound to and has the backends from your site. Are you sure everything is configured correctly, vhost on the backend, firewall? Make sure you setup realip for X-Forwarded-For header.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir, you were correct, I had SSH enabled on my backend and Cloudflare was looking for it. Now I must put SSH on the balancer.  Thanks!

Comment: As a follow up @Vladimir, why would the X-Forwarded-For header add my origin IP? Sometimes it adds a Cloudflare IP, which should be the last in the proxy chain, but most of the time it loads my origin IP, which I don't want.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Not sure what your exact setup is and what exactly is reaching your sites, but I'm guessing you know what that header is used for in the first place, so that the logging, and for various other uses the balancer IP doesn't end up as the client IP. But I am confused, do you want to see the clients' IP, or the IP of the proxy (in your case nginx LB)?

Comment: It's best to reach out to supportATcloudflareDOTcom in these instances. I have a feel that what's going on here is that a cyclic loop is being created as the loadbalancer is sending requests back through CloudFlare: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171976-Error-1000-DNS-points-to-prohibited-IP Our support team are the best to advise on this, please do write in if you're still facing issues or anyone reading this faces similar issues.